# Disable Alt key Shortcuts on pressing Alt again

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a button on which I apply <kbd>ALT</kbd> key shortcut:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" Width="50" Height="50">_Hello</Button>
```

Now, if I pressed <kbd>ALT</kbd> Key underscore is displaying, but pressing the <kbd>ALT</kbd> again does not disappear underscore. Can this be done in XAML without using events?

Comment: <Button Click="Button_Click" Width="50" Height="50">_Hello</Button>